# Issue with TRIGGER INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I got this code of my trigger but it isn't working for some reason

```
    CREATE TRIGGER copia_detalle_xml AFTER INSERT ON tif_detallexml
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO tbl_rif (id, idDetalleXml, total_xml, subtotal_xml, iva_xml, fecha_operacion)
VALUES (new.idContador, new.idDetalleXml, new.doubleTotal, new.doubleSubtotal,new.duobleTotalImpuestosTrasladados, NOW());
```

I checked the name of this field many times and it's correct "new.duobleTotalImpuestosTrasladados"

It is inserting the data correctly in the table but not the field "duobleTotalImpuestosTrasladados", and I have no idea why, I hope you can help me to find the issue with my code.

INFO UPDATED

This is from "tbl_rif"

[image]

This is from tif_detallexml

[image]

where the field "iva_xml" is 0 it should be 13.79

Comment: What are the data types for all the 6 columns?

Comment: Is the data for this column being inserted into the actual table i.e. tif_detallexml? Could you post the data values?

Comment: @vmachan yeah, everything is working on tif_detallexml

Comment: So `tif_detallexml.duobleTotalImpuestosTrasladados` maps to `tbl_rif.iva_xml`. And `tif_detallexml.duobleTotalImpuestosTrasladados = 0` so  what is the value being set/inserted into `tbl_rif.iva_xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the problem was that I was working with code made by other person where I got all the info of the XML and I didn't see that there was a line where the field that I required was being updated not inserted, that is why the trigger "wasn't working", thank you all for you help and sorry.

Comment: This is exactly what I was getting at with the last part of my answer, to see if the values actually were sent or not

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the data inserted your `iva_xml` is a numeric type.

Check to see what value your sending to it, I don't think you're sending the right data format (numeric)

And don't forget the typo you have here, maybe you have the same typo in your code:

> duobleTotalImpuestosTrasladados

should be???

> doubleTotalImpuestosTrasladados

**Just for testing**

Could you try to define your trigger like this and see what's inserted in the table?

```
CREATE TRIGGER copia_detalle_xml AFTER INSERT ON tif_detallexml
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO tbl_rif (id, idDetalleXml, total_xml, subtotal_xml, iva_xml, fecha_operacion)
VALUES (new.idContador, new.idDetalleXml, new.doubleTotal, new.duobleTotalImpuestosTrasladados,new.doubleSubtotal, NOW());
```

Comment: The type of both are "double" and yes "duobleTotalImpuestosTrasladados" is the correct name, I know that look different to the rest of the fields but it's correct.

Comment: could you also post the inserted data from the `tif_detallexml` table

Comment: Just to try, could you manually insert data in that table to verify what error is given?

Comment: I think at this point you should ask your question at [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99838/discussion-between-davejal-and-hail-hydra).